# Failed browsing discovery document

Tags: identityserver4

I am trying to follow the quick start sample on my local Windows 10 with IIS. When I browse
"http://localhost:5000/.well-known/openid-configuration" however, I got "This site can't be reached" error with Chome. When I tried the same with IE, it still failed but with some more detail: "The device or resource (localhost) is not set up to accept connections on port '5000'.". All I did was following the doc of the quick start. Is there something I missed, such as configuring IIS is some way?

Comment: If you're using Visual Studio, check the Properties for the IS4 project.  If the "Enable SSL" box is checked, it will show a different port (e.g. https://localhost:44339).  Try using that port instead (and use "https" instead of "http").  Many of the prebuilt IS4 Quickstart templates default to using https.

Comment: I figured I need to change the project to use IIS, instead of the default IIS Express. And use the URL "http://localhost/IdentityServer/.well-known/openid-configuration", instead of localhost:5000... then, points my IIS' IdentityServer web app to my project folder. Now when I try it, I am getting a 404 error.

Comment: Thanks Bryan! But my Enable SSL was never checked. I am intended to use IIS, not IIS Express but I didn't realize IIS Express was the default so that's one of my problem. Now I think I changed it to use IIS but I am still getting 404. I think I don't understand the ".well-known/openid-configuration" part. I couldn't find those paths anywhere in the project. And I pretty sure that's why I am getting the 404. So where the ".well-known/openid-configuration" maps to?

Comment: The well-known config is not a physical path that you will see in the project.  It's a route mapping that IS4 creates dynamically as part of OpenIDConnect (it's part of the OIDC standard).  Unless you changed something, it should always be at the root of your site (http://localhost:1234/.well-known/openid-configuration).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Choose Kestrel as the startup project and then you will see the handy log in a console window. That will help you debug your connectivity issues. In the log you will see what port Kestrel is listening on.

Just choose the name of your project here instead of IIS Express:

[image]

Comment: Thanks Tore. I am assuming that Kestrel is the name of the client project(?) but I am not there yet. I am on the first step of the quick start doc, which is browsing the "discovery document" after the identity server is created and configured. Now I think I may need to I create an IIS web application named IdentityServer and mapped it's path to my identity project. So that's what I did but I am getting 404 error when I browse to "http://localhost/IdentityServer/.well-known/openid-configuration". Where is ".well-known/openid-configuration" supposed to map to? Or am I completely off here?

Comment: Thanks again Tore. I reloaded the project and it sees to be working now.

Comment: Kestrel is the the name of the built in web-server in ASP.NET Core and when you choose the second option in the picture you run it directly instead of doing a detour via ISS-Express. Kestrel is always executed in both options.

Comment: Thank you so much for the clarification Tore and it really helps! Just curious, is Kestrel just for the purpose of development/test and IIS will be used in production? Secondly, my drop-down menu looks different from yours - mine doesn't have the project name ("IdentityTest", in your case) under "IIS Express", I only have a "Self Host" there. Is that because I am using VS 2017 and .net Core 2?

Comment: IIS/IIS-Express never servers any .NET pages by it self, instead it always pass it on to a ASP.NET web-server internally. Kestrel is one of them, http.sys is the alternative. Both can be used live on the internet without IIS. see this page https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/servers

Comment: Thank you again Tore. Great info!